# How to add other shapes on a arrow in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an arrow between 2 coordinates

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[fill=blue,circle,text width=3cm]   (first) at (1,1) {};
   \node[fill=purple,circle,text width=3cm] (third) at (1,9) {};
   \draw [->] (first) -- (third);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the arrow to something like this, I want to add shapes on it, which can contain some text

[image]

---

### edit

what if the arrow is on a curve?[image]

Comment: No need of complex things: `\draw[->] (0,0)--(0.5,0)node[draw,fill=white]{A}--(1.5,0)node[draw,fill=white]{A}--(2.5,0)node[draw,fill=white]{A}--(3,0);` then you can add width, height as you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can draw nodes on top of a path using the `pos=x` option, where `x` is a number between 0 (which represents the start of the path) and 1 (which represents the end). In your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
 my box/.style = {rectangle, draw=black, fill=white, minimum width=2.5em,
  }
}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=blue,circle,text width=3cm] (first) at   (1,1) {};
    \node[fill=purple,circle,text width=3cm] (third) at (9,1) {};
    \draw [->] (first) -- (third) 
               node[pos=0.25, my box] {A}
               node[pos=0.5,  my box] {B}
               node[pos=0.75, my box] {C};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

This solution has the advantage that it works easily for non-horizontal or vertical paths too. Also, if you add `sloped` option in `my box/.style` this will cause the A, B, C boxes use the same slope than the arrow line:

```
\tikzset{
 my box/.style = {rectangle, draw=black, fill=white, minimum width=2em, sloped,
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[fill=blue,circle,text width=1cm] (first) at   (1,1) {};
   \node[fill=purple,circle,text width=1cm] (third) at (7,-3) {};
   \draw [-latex] (first) -- (third) 
              node[pos=0.35, my box] {A}
              node[pos=0.5,  my box] {B}
              node[pos=0.65, my box] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result sloped]

## Update

Answering a question of the OP in a comment, the above works for curved paths as long as the path is specfied using the `..` syntax, and including the Bezier control points. For example:

```
\tikzset{
 my box/.style = {rectangle, draw=black, fill=white, minimum width=2em, sloped,
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[fill=blue,circle,text width=1cm] (first) at   (1,1) {};
   \node[fill=purple,circle,text width=1cm] (third) at (7,-3) {};
   \draw [-latex] (first) .. controls (+5,0) and +(-5,0) .. (third) 
              node[pos=0.2, my box] {A}
              node[pos=0.5, my box] {B}
              node[pos=0.8, my box] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Curved path]

<s>However, it does not work with `to` syntax, which would be more convenient:</s> **Update**: `to` syntax is also supported as long as the `node`s are put before the final coordinate (thanks to mwibrow for the hint!), so the following also works:

```
\tikzset{
 my box/.style = {rectangle, draw=black, fill=white, minimum width=2em, sloped,
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[fill=blue,circle,text width=1cm] (first) at   (1,1) {};
   \node[fill=purple,circle,text width=1cm] (third) at (7,-3) {};
   \draw [-latex] (first) to[out=0, in=180] 
              node[pos=0.3, my box] {A}
              node[pos=0.5, my box] {B}
              node[pos=0.7, my box] {C}
          (third);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Using to]

Comment: how to make it work for curved paths?

Comment: thanks...where can I find more info on how to use controls and bezier to correctly draw my curve ?

Comment: @user494461 You can read Wikipedia about the general idea of Bezier cuvres. Tikz syntax is `(P0) .. controls (P1) and (P2) .. (P3)`. This defines a curve which starts at `P0`, and ends at `P3`, being the starting of the curve tangent to the line `P0--P1` and the end of the curve tangent to `P2--P3`.  You can think of the control points as "magnets" which "pull" the curve.. You can specify the coordinates of  control points `P1` and `P2` relative of those of `P0` and `P3`, respectively, by puting `+` in fromt of them, as I did in the example of my answer.

Comment: For reasons I can't recall, nodes on `to` paths must go _before_ the final coordinate. So if you put the three nodes before `(third)` the nodes are positioned correctly.